# With Azure blob storage we need Application's user specific file access, Is there any way to achieve?

Tags: asp.net, azure, file-permissions, azure-blob-storage, user-permissions

We are try to using blob storage to save our application's files and documents on Azure's blob storage and we have requirement user specific files access. At this point any one can see any of the files.I don't want to do that. User should access their own files only if the other files they are trying to see or access then that should be redirected to the login page and should shows them you don't have access permission.

How can I achieve this with Azure's blob storage? I have tried to find some solution around this but I can't if any one can help then that would be very help full.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use Shared Access Signatures, in combination with your existing application's user store, authentication and authorization mechanisms, to control Azure blob access:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/windows-azure/901/protect-azure-blob-storage-shared-access-signature

You can adjust the timeouts, store the access keys, etc. as your application requires.

Comment: Thanks Henry it was helpful, Thanks Henry I did the same way that you told. Now if file is not accessible then giving un authorized message I want to redirect that to our application login page and once he loged in and still not he authorized to that file then I want to give custom error page to show as per our theme, Is this possible with blob storage?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how we did it in our application. Please see if this approach can be used in your application.

In our application, every user is assigned a unique id (a GUID). When the user signs up, we create a blob container and the name of this blob container is set as the id of the user. All the files for that user are kept in that blob container. When the user needs to access those files, we simply create a Shared Access Signature (SAS) for that blob container with appropriate permissions and share that SAS with that user (as mentioned by Henry in his answer).

Depending on the number of users, you may also want to consider load balancing these containers across multiple storage accounts. They way we have accomplished this is when a user signs up, we randomly assign a storage account from a pool of storage accounts and the blob container for that user is created in that storage account.

Comment: Thanks gaurav I did the same way that you told and use the @Henry solution as well. Now if file is not accessible then giving un authorized message I want to redirect that to login page and once he loged in and still not he authorized to that file then I want to give custom error page to show as per our theme, Is this possible with blob storage?

Comment: With blob storage, it is not possible to do custom error pages. This is something you would need to do in your application i.e. check if the user has access to the blob. If they don't then redirect them to an error page otherwise allow them to view/download the blob.

Comment: thatnks for your quick reply. the problem is what if I uploaded one image file for one user and there is a blob file path of that image file and other user who don't have access of that file and directly put in browser then he can't open and giving message by Azure blob but here I want to give custom message as this is direct path not through our application. What will be the solution for this?

Comment: If someone takes the blob URL and directly puts that in the browser, they will get standard error message from Azure Storage. You can't customize that. Only way to prevent that is never expose blob's actual URL and have everything route through your application. Then you will have things in your control.

Comment: Please refrain from asking new questions in comments as things get lost in comments. I would recommend asking a separate question. Thanks.